# Operator/operand type mismatch

Tags: oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm using the [Visual FoxPro OLE DB provider](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) to query a VFP DB and I'm getting:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   'Operator/operand type mismatch`

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `where` clause I had an `int` on one side and a `char(15)` on the other side

Table Schema

```
id int
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM [some-table]
WHERE id = 'some string'
```

Comment: well some-table will need to be bounded in some way to distinguish from some minus table and some dash table. SQL/Server would use [some-table] but I don't know what FoxPro uses.

Comment: While this syntax is wrong, it is not a question but a pseudo code with typos in it, right? For the mismatch case, in real life you would use parameters and thus wouldn't this problem of having or not having quotes.

Comment: @Ciarán, with VFP you could use [some-table] too, or 'some-table' or "some-table". IOW VFP needs a string "name" there and [], '' and "" are interchangeable. The real problem was comparing an int to a string (VFP wouldn't do implicit conversions as say MS SQL server from a string like '1' to an int, it needs to be without quotes if literals are used).

Answer (score 0):

In my case to avoid such kind of inconveniences I do the following I hope it works for you:

```
var_name = iif(vartype(var_name)=='N',var_name,Val(var_name))
```

so you avoid two possible errors, if it comes in character with value I convert it into number and if it comes in character without any value it becomes 0.

```
SELECT *
FROM [some-table]
WHERE id = ?Var_name
```