# Is there a way to avoid numeric to string conversion in where clause?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dbf

I'm building a web with PHP and Codeigniter 3, and I have to bring data from some .dbf databases, and I'm having some trouble with data types.

The table has a field that stores numbers as id, but his type is "**text**". Things is, no matter if I send a **number** or **string** in the Where clause, I receive a "*Operator/operand type mismatch*" error.
I think it's because even when I pass a string, it ends converted to a numeric type. I checked the db object and the where condition shows '*condition:"id_field = 00000002"*'. Is there a way to avoid this?
I tried putting some vfp functions in the where clause like *CAST* or *STR*, or "*strval*" from PHP, but no success 'till now.
It should be noted that I have little experience with PHP, dbf and VFP, so I may be pointing in the wrong direction.

Aniway...the code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->where("id_field", "22");
$query = $this->db->get();
$query = $query->result_array();

return $query;
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Who is creating the SQL?

Comment: Mm I'm not sure I understand. Codeigniter with the Query builder?

Comment: Have you tried explicit casting  - `$str = (string) 5;` returns '5'

Comment: Yep, I did. Still ends like "id_field = 5" and I get the same error.

Comment: `$this->db->where("id_field", 22);`

Comment: @Gundwane You might wanna take a look at - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp

Comment: @Vickel I'm gonna get an int with that line. And I want the opposite

Comment: @sauhardnc Tried it, but no luck.

Comment: can you show the complete error message?

Comment: @Vickel Sure thing: "com_exception: Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxProDescription: Operator/operand type mismatch."
I definitely think it's because PHP translates it as a numeric type. I tried with 'id_field = "22"' and it worked. I'm using an array to use dynamic filters. Guess I'm gonna get rid of that, and build an ugly string with every filter : (

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809017/operator-operand-type-mismatch

Comment: I ended up building a string query, adding single quotes to it. Looks horrible, but works so far.